# Need help in getting below output in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have table containing two columns as below.

```
Object  Value        
------  ------
OBJ1    200   
OBJ2    300  
OBJ2    400  
OBJ1    100
```

I need  out put as below

```
OBJ1    OBJ2                     
----    -----
300     700
```

can you help me on this?

Comment: or you can do a pivot/unpivot.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [PIVOT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( Object, Value ) AS
  SELECT  'OBJ1', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  'OBJ2', 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  'OBJ2', 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  'OBJ1', 200 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
select  *
from    your_table
PIVOT   ( SUM( value ) FOR Object IN ( 'OBJ1', 'OBJ2' ) );
```

**Output**:

```
OBJ1 OBJ2
---- ----
 400  700
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness another possibility:

```
select sum(case when object='OBJ1' then value else 0 end) as obj1,
       sum(case when object='OBJ2' then value else 0 end) as obj2
  from yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  select * from
    (select sum(value) Obj1 from yourTable where object= 'OBJ1 ') t1,
    (select sum(value) Obj2 from yourTable where object= 'OBJ2 ') t2
```

Comment: Why use one select when 3 will do?

Comment: It's just a solution